# How to resolve this insect infestation on fig tree leaves

Tags: insects, figs

Every time my fig tree sprouts new leave, it gets infested with this insect. Interestingly, I have lemon, guava, and curry tree, very close by and none of them are affected. Apparently, this insect loves only the fig tree.

Can someone please help me identify and get rid of this insect. I also have a bee hive nearby so if there is an option that spares the bees, I would prefer that.

[image: insect eggs and web on fig leaf]
[image: insect larvae caterpillers on fig leaf]

Answer (score -1):

Judging by the small black dots, and the webbing, I suspect that those are [Spider Mites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_mite). I have had these on leaves on trees in my garden previously. Luckily they don't attach strongly so they can be washed off easily with a decent jet of water, as long as the jet isn't strong enough to harm the plant. If a particular leaf is severely infested, it might be worth pruning, but that was never necessary for me.

For other methods of control [this page from the University of Colorado](https://extension.colostate.edu/topic-areas/insects/managing-houseplant-pests-5-595/) has some good information, as well some facts about the little critters themselves.

In terms of prevention increasing humidity and keeping plants well watered seems to do the trick, according to [this site](https://www.allaboutgardening.com/fiddle-leaf-fig-spider-mites/), though I have not tested these methods myself so mileage may vary.

[image]

[image]